# Javascript Prototype pub sub method out of scope

Tags: javascript, prototype, publish-subscribe

In my constructor I subscribe to another class function.  How do I call the class method show from within the subscribe.

```
var MemPortfolio = MemPortfolio || {};
MemPortfolio.Portfolio = function (contentid, thumbclass, featuredid) {
    this.thumbClass = thumbclass;
    this.featuredId = "#" + featuredid;
    var that = this;
    //subscribe to menutile click
    $.subscribe("/menutile/click/portfolio", function (tilename) {
        that.Show();
    });
};

MemPortfolio.Portfolio.prototype.Show = function () {
    alert("show");

}
```

In my doc ready:
/// 
///

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //check exists?
    var tilemenu = new MemTileMenu.Menu("menu", "menuitem", "contentarea");
    var portfolio = new MemPortfolio.Portfolio("contentarea", "thumb", "");
});
```

I got this working -

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.7.1.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.ba-tinypubsub.js" />
var MemPortfolio = MemPortfolio || {};
MemPortfolio.Portfolio = function (contentid, thumbclass, featuredid) {
    this.thumbClass = thumbclass;
    this.featuredId = "#" + featuredid;    
};

MemPortfolio.Portfolio.prototype = {

    show: function () {
        alert("show");
    },
    subscribe: function () {
        var that = this;
        $.subscribe("/menutile/click/portfolio", function (tilename) {
            that.show();
        });
    }
```

Doc.Ready here:

```
/// <reference path="tilemenu.js" />
/// <reference path="portfolio.js" />
$(document).ready(function () {
    //check exists?
    var tilemenu = new MemTileMenu.Menu("menu", "menuitem", "contentarea");
    var portfolio = new MemPortfolio.Portfolio("contentarea", "thumb", "");
    portfolio.subscribe();
});
    }
```

Thanks.
NerdPerson

Comment: If `Portfolio` was invoked using `new`, then you're doing it right now.

Comment: I get object doesn't support property or method

Comment: So you're saying you did use `new`? If so, then you're invoking it before the `MemPortfolio.Portfolio.prototype.Show = function () {` code had a chance to run.

Comment: That seems right? What's the problem?

Comment: You really need to put it all together for us. There's no way to know the order in which your code is running. Given a proper order of execution, your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/LVnqw/

Comment: Perhaps it was IE issue?  My code worked in your fiddle but not in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
  /// <reference path="jquery-1.7.1.js" />
    /// <reference path="jquery.ba-tinypubsub.js" />
    var MemPortfolio = MemPortfolio || {};
    MemPortfolio.Portfolio = function (contentid, thumbclass, featuredid) {
        this.thumbClass = thumbclass;
        this.featuredId = "#" + featuredid;    
    };

    MemPortfolio.Portfolio.prototype = {

        show: function () {
            alert("show");
        },
        subscribe: function () {
            var that = this;
            $.subscribe("/menutile/click/portfolio", function (tilename) {
                that.show();
            });
        }
    Doc.Ready here:

    /// <reference path="tilemenu.js" />
    /// <reference path="portfolio.js" />
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //check exists?
        var tilemenu = new MemTileMenu.Menu("menu", "menuitem", "contentarea");
        var portfolio = new MemPortfolio.Portfolio("contentarea", "thumb", "");
        portfolio.subscribe();
    });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `MemPortfolio.Portfolio.prototype` by `MemPortfolio.prototype.Portfolio`